# Pagination doesn't work when there is orderByRaw

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination, eloquent

thanks for reading.

I have a method that take data from a table, with an **orderByRaw** sentence.

Everything is ok unless when I want to do a pagination, which without the **orderByRaw** works perfectly.

I've seen here a solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207222/laravel-pagination-links-not-appearing#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207222/laravel-pagination-links-not-appearing#_=_) but I wanted to know if there is another better solution.

My controller looks like this:

```
    public function search() {
        $parameters = Input::get('a');

        $query = Project::whereRaw("MATCH(name, description_es, description_en, resources_es, resources_en, base_address, addresses) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", array($parameters));

        $query->orderByRaw("MATCH(name, description_es, description_en, resources_es, resources_en, base_address, addresses) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC", array($parameters));


        if (Input::get('selfmanaged')) {
            $query->where('selfmanaged', 1);
        }

        if (Input::get('vegan')) {
            $query->where('vegan', 1);
        }

        $projects = $query->paginate(5);

        return View::make('list', compact('projects', 'parameters'));
    }
```

And in the view I have:

```
    <div id='pagination'>{{ $projects->appends(array('a' => $parameters))->links() }}</div>
```

Thank you so much for your time!